# Using `argparse` to handle arguments when it is already defined in a super class

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, alexa-skills-kit

I am using the Alexa Gadget Toolkit Python package to create an IoT device. (https://github.com/alexa/Alexa-Gadgets-Raspberry-Pi-Samples/tree/master/src/agt)

Following from Amazon's example scripts, the IoT class is defined and executed as:

```
from agt import AlexaGadget

class MyGadget(AlexaGadget):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyGadget().main()
```

I'd like to add an additional "test" argument to my gadget script (to enter a testing mode), so I am using `argparser`.

```
import argparse
from agt import AlexaGadget

class MyGadget(AlexaGadget):
    def main():
        super().main()
        
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("--test", action="store_true", required=False)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.test:
            # Do something here
```

However, when I do this, *reagardless of whether or not I call the `super().main()` before or after defining `parser`*, I receive:

```
usage: mygadget.py [-h] [--pair] [--clear]
mygadget.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --test
```

Looking at the AGT class, they also use `argparser` to define arguments related to the Bluetooth functionality.

**Since it is already defined in the parent, how can I also capture my own arguments in my child without modifying Amazon's AGT class?**

Thanks!

Comment: Each parser runs independently looking at the same `sys.argv` commandline list.  While your own parser can handle extras with `parse_unknown_args` you can't do anything with the other.  I wonder if there's a point where you can remove the `--test` argument from `sys.argv` before AGT looks at it.

Comment: Thanks right yeah I will look into that method. I will add a comment to the Alexa GitHub to see if they can change their class.

Comment: With some of the Google tools  (youtube access etc), it's possible call them in a non-script manner that doesn't run the parser.   Other packages like `ipython` let you supply your own arguments after a delimiter like '--'.